What is the best method for measuring high voltage capacitor?
I am looking for a method to measure the capacitance of a 2500 V (rated) film capacitor.
Multimeter and LCR meter, measure the capacitance in low voltage, therefore it's expected that the measurement not accurate for the working voltage.
I thought about using RC time constant in the charging or discharging cycle. However, I encountered with some ambiguity/problem. In this method, the voltage changed between 0 through 2500 V, and therefore supposed to that the capacitance changes with voltage and the time constant changed. Therefore, the accuracy of this method be questionable. Besides, I have no special instruments for measuring high voltage. I can used resistance divider, or high voltage probe of oscilloscope, but the accuracy of them is unknown too.
I am thinking about designing of a circuit, to charge the capacitor to 2500 V, and injecting small signal AC to the capacitor for impedance measurement in different frequency.
However, before start designing the circuit, the question raised that what's the best method to measure the HV capacitance? Can anyone introduce a book, paper or link?

Why not choose a capacitor that has guaranteed capacitance across the voltage range?

I'll assume you have several capacitors from the same batch, not just one.
You can then measure two in series, completely independently of the bias voltage on them. The measurement configuration stays the same, whether the bias is zero or kV, so you can confidently detect small changes in capacitance with bias voltage.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
SW1 may or may not be required. If you measure at a frequency where the impedance of Rbias is much greater than that of your capacitors under test, then you can leave the bias connected and ignore, or make a small adjustment for, Rbias. Otherwise open SW1 for measurement, performing the measurement before DC leakage changes the voltage on the capacitors significantly.
SW2 is just for safety, to protect your capacitance meter. You might want to leave it closed while adjusting the bias voltage, only opening it for measurements once the bias voltage has settled.
Your meter should have information about its own internal protection against external voltages and currents being applied when measuring capacitance. You might need further protection if that's not adequate to cope with, for instance, you measure with SW1 open, and the two capacitors have significantly different leakage rates.

I tested this method for measuring the capacitor. Just some points I saw in my test.

I used a fly-back circuit to charge the parallel capacitors at first. Then I disconnected fly-back converter from the capacitors and change the configuration from parallel connection to series connection, instead of using SW1 and SW2.



The insulation resistance of the implemented circuit is very important, and large clearances should be considered preventing discharge of capacitor.
When I charged the capacitor using fly-back and quickly changed to connection from series to parallel, I saw that the voltage of series connection increase. But keeping the voltage bias for about 5 mins on the parallel connection and then changing the configuration to series, resulted in less voltage change.


You could charge it to your maximum desired voltage, then discharge it with a constant current sink and measure its voltage over time.
$$C(V)=I_C\frac{dt}{dV}$$
Still consider, that your voltmeter will draw a little bit of current too, so either make \$I_C\$ sufficiently large or modify the equation to take the voltmeter current into account.
A slightly better method is to ramp up and down in separate measurements. This will let you determine the capacitive (\$I_C\$) and resistive leakage currents separately.
To simplify it on the other hand: You don't need a constant current sink. The formula above holds for variable currents too. So you can discharge with a resistor, but you need to monitor the discharge current over time, as you discharge the capacitance.
